# Creating lists of connections from text file

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have this problem. I want to find all connections within list of lists created from a text file. Example data in my file:

```
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_DEPOSIT
CUSTOMER_DETAIL BALANCE
BFG_2056 FFD_15
BALANCE BFG_16
BFG_16 STAT_HIST
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_2056
CUSTOM_DATA AND_11
AND_11 DICT_DEAL
DICT_DEAL BFG_2056
```

and I create list of lists using this code.

```
data = [line.split() for line in open('data.txt')
```

I get something like this:

```
[[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT],[CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE],[BFG_2056, FFD_15],[BALANCE,BFG_16],[BFG_16,STAT_HIST],[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_2056],[CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11],[AND_11,DICT_DEAL],[DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056]]
```

So what I want is that we take first list from data:
[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT]
and we try to find BFG_DEPOSIT in other lists, but BFG_DEPOSIT must be in first place.
 So for this we can see that we dont have any connections.
 Then again we try to find for [CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE] so we get [CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE,BFG_16,STAT_HIST]. We do it as long as there is connection and for every list. If there isn't one we return the list of those connections.
First time I created dict from this data and found all paths using this code:

```
def get_path(key,my_dict):
    if key not in my_dict:
        return None
    result = []
    curr = key
    while curr and len(result) <= len(my_dict):
        result.append(curr)
        curr = my_dict.get(curr,None)
        curr = key
    return result

for key,item in data.items():
    final[key]=get_path('{}'.format(key),data)
```

But I had duplicates of keys which must be preserved so dictionary was out. I tried using recursion, but to no avail.

```
def get_simple_path(item, main_list, result):
    result.append(item[0])
    for i in main_list:
        if i[0] == item[1]:
            get_simple_path(i, main_list, result)

wynik = []

for i in data:
    result=[]
    wynik.append(get_simple_path(i,data,result))
```

Someone suggested to me to implement this using linked lists but I still don't know how to find all connections. The output that I'm looking for looks something like this:
so for this data

```
[[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT],[CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE],[BFG_2056, FFD_15],[BALANCE,BFG_16],[BFG_16,STAT_HIST],[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_2056],[CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11],[AND_11,DICT_DEAL],[DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056]]
```

I want all connections to look like this:

```
[

[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT],
[CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE,BFG_16,STAT_HIST],
[BFG_2056,FFD_15],
[BALANCE,BFG_16,STAT_HIST],
[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_2056,FFD_15],
[CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11,DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15],
[AND_11,DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15],
[DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15]
]
```

Comment: ...not sure on how exactly your desired output should look like, can you add a small example?

Comment: @cards I added example of what I want.

Comment: That will risk to be a long list. Imagine a *complete* graph with 10 nodes. You will get as output all permutations of the node-labels. How will that output of 3,6 million paths be useful?

Comment: but what is the rule to split the list of pair [[pre, suc], ...]?

Comment: @trincot It could be a tree, but It will never be a complete tree, because the data that I have can't have connections between two childs. The data is useful for me because I want to simplify the data map.

Comment: *"It could be a tree"*: But not certain? So it could have cycles? Could you please provide a complete, concrete example in your question (no "..."). Also: is the graph directed?

Comment: @trincot added the rest for example.

Comment: @trincot maybe easier it is to think about it as a dictionary. We have pairs of key:value and I want to find the value in keys and then We again try to find the value of found key in keys etc. but I can't use dictionary.

Comment: Can you give an example where the graph is not a tree? The example you gave is quite trivial, as it represents just one linked list. Also: in your example output the path `["Table4"]` is not included. Is this because you have a rule that a path should at least have 2 nodes? I also assume your nodes are actually strings (but you represented them as variables).

Comment: @trincot I added better data. I don't include Table4 because as you said I want paths with at least 2 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way is to create an adjacency list. This would be a dictionary keyed by node labels, and with as values the *lists* of neighboring labels.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
def create_adj(edges):
    adj = {}   # or use defaultdict(list) to avoid `if` in the loop below
    for a, b in edges:
        if not a in adj:
            adj[a] = []
        if not b in adj:
            adj[b] = []
        adj[a].append(b)
    return adj

def all_paths(adj):
    def recur(path):
        node = path[-1]
        neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in adj[node] if not neighbor in path]
        if not neighbors:
            yield path
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            yield from recur(path + [neighbor])

    for node in adj:
        yield from recur([node])
```

Here is an example run:

```
data = [
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_DEPOSIT"],
    ["CUSTOMER_DETAIL","BALANCE"],
    ["BFG_2056", "FFD_15"],
    ["BALANCE","BFG_16"],
    ["BFG_16","STAT_HIST"],
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_2056"],
    ["CUSTOM_DATA","AND_11"],
    ["AND_11","DICT_DEAL"],
    ["DICT_DEAL","BFG_2056"]
]

adj = create_adj(data)

print([path for path in all_paths(adj) if len(path) > 1])
```

Note that `all_paths` will also include paths with length 1, which is why they are excluded with a condition on the length in the final print out.

Comment: I tested it on new example data that I added and I think it works fine, but will check for my DataMap and then accept it as an answer. Still, thanks !

Comment: Hey I know that I accepted your answer already, but do you maybe know how I could get the same result using pandas dataframe ? This answer is great for small data pool but I have 13k rows.

Comment: I don't have experience with pandas, so I think it is better to ask a new question about that, and tag it with `pandas`.